# Деякі корисні онлайн-джерела / Some useful online sources

Tags: discussion, faq, resources, info

В цьому питанні я сам створив відповідь. Це є wiki-відповідь (спільна відповідь, community wiki) — **її може редагувати кожен**. Ви можете додавати інші джерела: редагуючи ту відповідь або створювати окремі відповіді.

- [Загальне](/a/9) / General
- [Словники](/a/287) / Dictionaries
- [Корпуси](/a/286) / Corporas
- [Правописи](/a/119) / Spelling
- [Пошук у локалізаціях програм](/a/56) / Search in software localizations
- [Перелік ресурсів](/a/100) / List of sourses
- Wikipedia, Wiktionary: [Джерела](/a/130) / Sources
- [Учба](/a/190) / Learning
- [Здоровий глузд](/a/152) / Common sense

---

In this question I created an answer myself. It's a wiki-answer (community answer, community wiki) — **everyone can edit it**. You're welcome to add other sources: by editing that (wiki) answer or by creating new ones.

Comment: Здається є різні погляди на  це питання. На сайті китайської мови цей список на основному сайті: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-mandarin-chinese, на англійському - в меті: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available/2574#2574 Колись на мета-блозі був пост про те що хоча на СтекОверфлоу питання про ресурси офтопік, на багатьох сайтах такі питання дозволено. З цієї точки зору якщо такі пости будуть дозволені і тут, мати головний пост на основному сайті буде набагато зручніше.

Comment: @Sasha  так. Хоча в китайців питання стояло навіть жорсткіше: чи потрібна взагалі така збірка ресурсів http://meta.chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/162/resources-for-learning-mandarin-chinese-should-we-have-it-at-all Особисто вважаю, що вона обов'язково має бути, лишень де?

Comment: Опитування про один загальний пост на основному сайті: http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/40/69

Comment: @Sasha питання в стилі Community Wiki насправді взагалі-то створюється модератором, це є пост створений від імені спільноти і тому має особливий статус. Колись міг і звичайний юзер створити такий пост.

Comment: @Artemix, так, я в курсі, що створюється (точніше призначається статус Community Post'а) модератором. Хоча, що сам пост при цьому не зобов'язаний відповідати звичайним критеріям, не знав. Тим не менш, мені все одно здається неправильним робити те, що «звичайним» користувачам заборонено (можливо, якщо ми вимагаємо від користувачів не захламляти основний сайт неконкретними питаннями, то й самим таке робити не слід, навпаки маємо подавати приклад; навіть з доброю метою). :) Але я ще  подумаю, може, Ви й праві.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. Поради мовознавців: [«Як ми говоримо» Б. Антоненка-Давидовича](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/), [«Культура слова» О. Пономаріва](http://ponomariv-kultura-slova.wikidot.com/), [блог О. Пономаріва на BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/ukrainian/ponomariv/archives.html), [«Уроки державної мови» (в газеті «Хрещатик») Б. Рогози](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/index.html) <sub>(мовознавці іноді помиляються)</sub>, [відеоуроки О. Авраменка](http://xn--80aafnzkijm.xn--j1amh/11/12) (також [аудіоуроки](http://xn--80aafnzkijm.xn--j1amh/11/13)) <sub>(чи він мовознавець?)</sub>. 
   Неавторитетні поради: [список найтиповіших мовних помилок у Вікіпедії](http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA#cite_ref-dzvonadzvonu_1-0).
2. Інші спільноти: [Чиста мова](https://www.facebook.com/chystamova/), Мова – ДНК нації ([сторінка Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/mova.ukr), [сайт](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/)), [СловОпис](https://www.facebook.com/slovopys/), [ua-etymology](http://ua-etymology.livejournal.com/), [моволюбам](http://l-ponomar.com/), [movakrapka](http://movakrapka.blogspot.com/), [MOVA.info Q&A](http://www.mova.info/dovidka.aspx), [лінгвофорум](http://lingvoforum.net/index.php?board=101.0), [r2u мовні консультації](http://r2u.org.ua/forum/viewforum.php?f=6), [словопедія форум](http://www.slovopedia.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=12).
3. Підручники: [підготовка до ЗНО](http://zno.academia.in.ua/course/view.php?id=8), [від ІФ КНУ](http://www.linguist.univ.kiev.ua/WINS/pidruchn/), [на Phoenicis](https://www.phoenicis.com.ua/ukrainian-language.html)
4. Адаптація іноземних слів: правопис, [правила транслітерації ДСІВ](http://sips.gov.ua/ua/transliteruvannja.html), [правила транслітерації Укркартографії](http://ukrmap.com.ua/services/kodeksi-ustalenoji-praktiki/). 
   Неавторитетне джерело неологізмів: [Словотвір](http://slovotvir.org.ua/).
5. Для іноземців: [Speak Ukrainian](https://speakukraine.net/).

---

1. Linguists' advices : [“How do we speak” of B. Antonenko-Davydovych](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/), [“Culture of word” of O. Ponomariv](http://ponomariv-kultura-slova.wikidot.com/), [O. Ponomariv's blog at BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/ukrainian/ponomariv/archives.html), [“Lessons of the state language” (in the newspaper “Khreshchatyk”) of B. Rohoza](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/index.html) <sub>(linguists sometimes make mistakes too)</sub>, [O. Avramenko's video-lessons](http://xn--80aafnzkijm.xn--j1amh/11/12) (also [radio-lessons](http://xn--80aafnzkijm.xn--j1amh/11/13))<sub>(is he a linguist?)</sub>. 
   Non-authoritative advices: [list of the most common lingual mistakes in Wikipedia](http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA#cite_ref-dzvonadzvonu_1-0).
2. Other communities: [Chysta mova](https://www.facebook.com/chystamova/), Mova a.k.a. mova.ukr ([Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/mova.ukr), [site](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/)), [SlovOpys](https://www.facebook.com/slovopys/), [ua-etymology](http://ua-etymology.livejournal.com/), [l-ponomar](http://l-ponomar.com/), [movakrapka](http://movakrapka.blogspot.com/), [MOVA.info Q&A](http://www.mova.info/dovidka.aspx), [lingvoforum](http://lingvoforum.net/index.php?board=101.0), [r2u lingual consultations](http://r2u.org.ua/forum/viewforum.php?f=6), [slovopedia forum](http://www.slovopedia.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=12).
3. Textbooks: [preparation to EIT](http://zno.academia.in.ua/course/view.php?id=8), [from IP of KNU](http://www.linguist.univ.kiev.ua/WINS/pidruchn/), [on Phoenicis](https://www.phoenicis.com.ua/ukrainian-language.html).
4. Foreign words adaptation: orthography, [SIPS transliteration rules](http://sips.gov.ua/ua/transliteruvannja.html), [Ukrmap transliteration rules](http://ukrmap.com.ua/services/kodeksi-ustalenoji-praktiki/). 
   Non-authoritative neologism source: [Словотвір](http://slovotvir.org.ua/).
5. For foreigners: [Speak Ukrainian](https://speakukraine.net/).

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist, some consider "хохол" to be ethnic slur (ethnophaulism). Although acceptance of the word differ: some Russians use this word without any negative connotation (considering it neutral) and historically many Ukrainians did the same. Certainly this is not a profanity; but most consider it pejorative; maybe it really should be  uncensored.

Comment: I'm well-aware of the derogatory aspect of хохол, but we're guided by the Be Nice policy of SE. We won't tolerate directed ethnic abuse, but hoholpedia is a proper name, probably firmly-in-cheek and picked intentionally to reclaim the word, which by now is considered pretty tame. Aside from that, once you click on your censored links there's a huge graphic with the word and it appears clearly in the browser address bar. Why bother then?

Comment: «Український національний лінгвістичний корпус» УМІФ - does not allow to open the application - is there a documentation on this application? Do they register users in some other place (a site, an organization?) Or they have some weird requirements to user name and password? I'm trying to enter different names using cyrillic and latin letters but it always gives me an error.

Comment: @Artemix, sorry, I don't know. Under GNU/Linux I see only [this](http://archive.is/LHdX3) (that's a [ClickOnce manifest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce#Manifests) hardly-usable on Linux) — that's why I added notice "for Windows only". Probably on Windows you should click "Run" and then you'll smth like [on this picture](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/40/Click1c.PNG/387px-Click1c.PNG) — but in fact I **never** tried to user it from Windows (maybe it even requires Internet Explorer, I don't know).

Comment: @Artemix, there some docs and screenshots over Internet (e.g. [this](http://man.gov.ua/files/49/ORHANIZATsIYA.pdf)), but as I never used ULIF corpus myself, I can't advice any specific. Maybe you should contact ULIF or start separate discussion here on meta (in case some of use had used it), I don't know. If it really doesn't work, it should be removed from sources, but I don't know anything about its current state.

Comment: @Sasha Воно запускається але далі ніж це вікно не пускає: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQ3Nr.png

Comment: @Sasha In your document I have found this: "Користувач — логін користувача (виділяється адміністратором при
занесенні інформації про користувача до системи).Пароль ...(видається адміністратором ...). Вхід до системи без реєстрації неможливий. Для реєстрації необхідні логін та пароль." So it is not usable by "any user" as it is.

Comment: @Artemix, що ж, якщо воно справді вимагає реквізити, які мають не всі (але хтось — наприклад, можливо, студенти/викладачі КНУ чи ті, хто особисто написали e-mail адмну «дайте мені, будь ласка, доступ» — має), то його, мабуть, слід вилучити з цього переліку і створити нижче окрему відповіть «корисні онлайн-ресурси з обмеженим доступом» (я сумніваюся, що вони деплоїли би це онлайн, якщо вони не дають логін/пароль взагалі нікому).

Answer (score 9):

## Правописи

<sub>Позначення:

 — оригінал-макет або скан (точна копія);

 — результат розпізнавання або переформатування (можливі невеликі неточності);

 — приблизний опис чи переказ;

<del>закреслення</del> — джерело вже зникло.</sub>

### XVIII ст.

1798. Котляревський:  [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE).

### XIX ст.

1893. Смаль-Стоцький і Ґартнер, «Руска граматика»:
       [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_1893_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83),
       [Збруч](https://zbruc.eu/node/66463).

### XX ст.

1914. Смаль-Стоцький і Ґартнер, «Граматика руської мови»:
       [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8),
       [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/hramatykarusko00smal),
       [Чтиво](https://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Smal-Stotskyi_Stepan/Hramatyka_ruskoi_movy),
       [Чтиво](https://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Smal-Stotskyi_Stepan/Hramatyka_ruskoi_movy_vyd_1914).

1917. «Коротенька українська правопись» часопису «Рідне Слово»:
       [Культура України](https://elib.nlu.org.ua/view.html?id=11914),
       [Diasporiana](https://diasporiana.org.ua/movoznavstvo/korotka-ukrayinska-pravopys).


      «Граматична термінологія і правопись, ухвалені комісією мови при Українському товаристві шкільної освіти в Київі (1917)» Української Центральної Ради:
       [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/grammar_terminology_n_spelling_1917),
       [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx3rm-9lOt18aFYyenNDNzl2MHc) (від [korchiwjaka](https://korchiwjaka.blogspot.com/2013/01/1917.html)).

1919. Смаль-Стоцький і Ґартнер, «Руска правопись зі словарцем», 3-тє видання:
       [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/ruskapravopyszis00smal),
       [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/cihm_76668).


      Смаль-Стоцький і Ґартнер, «Українська граматика»:
       [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/ukranskahramatyk00smal),
       [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/ukranskahramatyk00smal_0),
       [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/cihm_77796),
       [Чтиво](https://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Smal-Stotskyi_Stepan/Ukrainska_hramatyka).

1921. «Найголовніші правила українського правопису»:
       [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81_1921_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83),
       [Культура України](https://elib.nlu.org.ua/view.html?id=9634),
       [Чтиво](https://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Krymskyi_Ahatanhel/Naiholovnishi_pravyla_ukrainskoho_pravopysu).
      Нове видання (1925):
       [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx3rm-9lOt18amdicVhvZVRBXzA) (від [korchiwjaka](https://korchiwjaka.blogspot.com/2012/12/1925.html)).

1922. «Головніші правила українського правопису»:
       [Культура України](https://elib.nlu.org.ua/view.html?id=10541),
       [Diasporiana](https://diasporiana.org.ua/movoznavstvo/golovnishi-pravyla-ukrayinskogo-pravopysu).


      «Правописні правила, приняті Науковим товариством імени Шевченка у Львові»:
       [Культура України](https://elib.nlu.org.ua/view.html?id=10577).

1925. Огієнко:
       [Культура України](https://elib.nlu.org.ua/view.html?id=11911).

1926. «Харківський», проєкт для ознайомлення:
       [movahistory](http://movahistory.org.ua/index.php/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81._(%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%94%D0%BA%D1%82)._1926_%D1%80.).

1928. «Харківський», проєкт:
       [movahistory](http://movahistory.org.ua/index.php/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81._(%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%94%D0%BA%D1%82)._1928_%D1%80.).


      «Харківський», гранки для коректури:
       [Histor!ans](https://web.archive.org/web/20190331080308/https://www.historians.in.ua/index.php/en/monografii/552-ukrainskyi-pravopys-kharkiv-derzhavne-vydavnytstvo-ukrainy-1928-r-101-s).

      Наконечний, «Про новий правопис український»:
       [Культура України](https://elib.nlu.org.ua/view.html?id=9981),
       [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx3rm-9lOt18bEVFZy1oUWpCM0E) (від [korchiwjaka](https://korchiwjaka.blogspot.com/2013/03/pro-novyj-pravopys-ukrajinskyj-1928.html)).

1929. «Харківський»:
       [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81),
       [R2U](https://r2u.org.ua/node/181),
       [R2U](https://r2u.org.ua/data/other/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81-1928.pdf),
       [Україніка](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/ulib/item/UKR0009938),
       [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx3rm-9lOt18T0ZLaWNlN3hrUzA) (від [korchiwjaka](https://korchiwjaka.blogspot.com/2012/12/1929.html)),
       [movahistory](http://movahistory.org.ua/index.php/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81._1928_%D1%80.),
       [Мечнікова](https://web.archive.org/web/20220309095729/http://rarebook.onu.edu.ua:8081/handle/123456789/9765).
      Львівське видання (зі словничком):
       [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1roHQxVLmwflXSxYFwiS02FmIbX5ZmBTD) (від [korchiwjaka](https://korchiwjaka.blogspot.com/2022/01/1929-1928.html)).


      Гладкий, «Новий український правопис»:
       [Культура України](https://elib.nlu.org.ua/view.html?id=9416).


      Грунський, «Основи нового українського правопису»:
       [Культура України](https://elib.nlu.org.ua/view.html?id=9425).


      Синявський, «Найголовніші правила української мови (за новим правописом)»:
       [Україніка](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/ulib/item/0001537).
      Друге видання:
       [Культура України](https://elib.nlu.org.ua/view.html?id=10659).

1933. Хвиля:
       [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81_1933_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83),
       [Україніка](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/ulib/item/UKR0009919),
       [movahistory](http://movahistory.org.ua/index.php/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81._1933_%D1%80.),
       [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx3rm-9lOt18SHBTeGxVeDN1T2c) (від [korchiwjaka](https://korchiwjaka.blogspot.com/2012/12/1933.html)).
      Див. також: «Словник-покажчик до…»:
       [Культура України](https://elib.nlu.org.ua/view.html?id=10744) (1935).

1934. Хвиля, 2-ге видання:
       [eScriptorium](http://escriptorium.univer.kharkov.ua/handle/1237075002/10591).

1936. Хвиля, 3-тє видання:
       [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/1936_uk_spelling),
       [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c0PWlMjbmiMig9PKeQA7rYWcdgdAPm73) (від [Artem Dolotov](https://fb.com/groups/488552241633414/posts/1557990774689550/?comment_id=1560459901109304&reply_comment_id=1562585054230122)).

1938. Грунський, проєкт:
       [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%94%D0%BA%D1%82_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83_1939_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83),
       [movahistory](http://movahistory.org.ua/index.php/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81._(%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE)._1938%D1%80).

1940. Грунський, проєкт:
       [movahistory](http://movahistory.org.ua/index.php/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81._(%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE)._1940_%D1%80.).

1941. Синявський, «Норми української літературної мови»:
       [Україніка](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/ulib/item/UKR0001032),
       [R2U](https://r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/zmist),
       [Вікіджерела (частково)](https://uk.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9._%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8).
      Редакція Телемка з додатками:
       [R2U](https://r2u.org.ua/data/other/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97%20%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%97%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8,%20%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20(1941).pdf),
       [Чтиво](https://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Syniavskyi_Oleksa/Normy_ukrainskoi_literaturnoi_movy),
       <del>[Український Центр](http://www.ukrcenter.com/%D0%9B%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0/%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/54944/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97-%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%97-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8)</del>.

1942. Зілинський, 2-ге видання:
       [Культура України](https://elib.nlu.org.ua/view.html?id=10748).

1943. Зілинський, 3-те видання:
       [Культура України](https://elib.nlu.org.ua/view.html?id=12064),
       [Diasporiana](https://diasporiana.org.ua/movoznavstvo/15486-ukrayinskiy-pravopis),
       [movahistory](http://movahistory.org.ua/index.php/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81._%D0%A3%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B2_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%97%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9).


      Зілинський, 4-те видання:
       [Культура України](https://elib.nlu.org.ua/view.html?id=12092).

1945. радянський:
       [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/ukrainian_pravopys_1945),
       [Україніка](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/ulib/item/UKR0010302),
       [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZBBdVsBhx1KKCBwlCyWn2FWZmji3YXO7) (від [korchiwjaka](https://korchiwjaka.blogspot.com/2013/01/1945-1945.html)),
       [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx3rm-9lOt18OEpjWHB0UFNpRm8) (від [korchiwjaka](https://korchiwjaka.blogspot.com/2013/01/1945-1945.html));

1946. радянський:
       [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81_1946_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83),
       [Культура України](https://elib.nlu.org.ua/view.html?id=10274),
       [movahistory (частково)](http://movahistory.org.ua/index.php/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81._1946_%D1%80.).


      Шерех:
       [Культура України](https://elib.nlu.org.ua/view.html?id=11909),
       [Diasporiana](https://diasporiana.org.ua/movoznavstvo/2837-shereh-yu-golovni-pravila-ukrayinskogo-pravopisu).


      Ковалів:
       [Культура України](https://elib.nlu.org.ua/view.html?id=11915).

1949. Рудницький:
       [Diasporiana](https://diasporiana.org.ua/movoznavstvo/17387-rudnitskiy-ya-ukrayinskiy-pravopis/).

1960. радянський, 2-ге видання:
       [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81_1960_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83),
       [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/up-1960),
       [§ 41–42 на CTAN](https://mirrors.ctan.org/language/hyphenation/ukrhyph/rules60.pdf).

1977. Ковалів:
       [Diasporiana](https://diasporiana.org.ua/movoznavstvo/3485-kovaliv-p-ukrayinskiy-pravopis),
       [Україніка](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/ulib/item/UKR0010216).

1990. радянський, 3-тє видання:
       [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/1990_uk_spelling),
       [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18dGu2Mfrd1BPEZrY8e7i1nvCLGFhmEWq) (від [korchiwjaka](https://korchiwjaka.blogspot.com/2023/06/ukrajinskyj-pravopys-1990-roku.html));
      з коричневою обкладинкою:
       [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VWDWYzaJLaeuXutbCdMvZT220fjPcv6k) (звідти ж);
      без візерунка на обкладинці:
       [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_rn_tqUBxxGxvJgdXbp5KzJRtSgod7gF) (звідти ж).

1993. «4-те видання»:
       [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81_1993_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83),
       [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/1993_uk_spelling),
       [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_dH74U0-KVD8EHy9QirxbJN3J_sAp3em) (від [Artem Dolotov](https://fb.com/groups/488552241633414/posts/1557990774689550/?comment_id=1560459901109304&reply_comment_id=1562585054230122)),
       [Google Books (обмежено)](https://google.com/books?id=WKzqAAAAMAAJ),
       <del>[коледж НАУ](http://flightcollege.com.ua/library/8%20%D0%A4%D0%98%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%93%D0%98%D0%A7%D0%95%D0%A1%D0%9A%D0%98%D0%95%20%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%A3%D0%9A%D0%98/81%20%D0%AF%D0%97%D0%AB%D0%9A%D0%9E%D0%97%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%95/81.2%20%D0%A3%D0%9A%D0%A0/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%81%201994.djvu)</del>.

1996. «5-те видання»: ???.

1997. «6-те видання»:
       [Україніка](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/ulib/item/UKR0009746).

1998. «7-ме видання»:
       [§ 41–42 на CTAN](https://mirrors.ctan.org/language/hyphenation/ukrhyph/rules90.pdf).

1999. Німчук, проєкт:
       [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%94%D0%BA%D1%82_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83_1999_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83),
       [R2U](https://r2u.org.ua/pravopys/pravXXI/zmist.htm#proekt),
       [vlada.kiev.ua](https://web.archive.org/web/20120604210430/http://www.vlada.kiev.ua/pravopys/pravXXI/zmist.htm#proekt) ( [2](https://web.archive.org/web/20100913013850/http://pravopys.vlada.kiev.ua/pravopys/pravXXI/zmist.htm#proekt)),
       [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/1999_uk_project_spelling),
       [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DyT7Fl6iZmQY7WidFmE2XWsbQn867Exx) (від [korchiwjaka](https://korchiwjaka.blogspot.com/2023/01/pravopys-projekt-najnovishoji-redak.html)).

2000. <del>[коледж НАУ](http://flightcollege.com.ua/library/8%20%D0%A4%D0%98%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%93%D0%98%D0%A7%D0%95%D0%A1%D0%9A%D0%98%D0%95%20%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%A3%D0%9A%D0%98/81%20%D0%AF%D0%97%D0%AB%D0%9A%D0%9E%D0%97%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%95/81.2%20%D0%A3%D0%9A%D0%A0/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%81%20%202000.djvu)</del>.

### XXI ст.

2001. ???.

2003. Русанівський, проєкт:
       [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%94%D0%BA%D1%82_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83_2003_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83),
       [Ізборник](http://litopys.org.ua/pdf/proekt_2003.pdf) ( [2](http://izbornyk.org.ua/pdf/proekt_2003.pdf)),
       [ДУТ](https://dut.edu.ua/ua/lib/1/category/96/view/848),
       [Google Books (обмежено)](https://google.com/books?id=XLdiAAAAMAAJ).


       [Україніка](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/ulib/item/UKR0009469).

2004. ???.

2005. ???.

2007. [Україніка](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/ulib/item/UKR0001517),
       <del>[коледж НАУ](http://flightcollege.com.ua/library/8%20%D0%A4%D0%98%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%93%D0%98%D0%A7%D0%95%D0%A1%D0%9A%D0%98%D0%95%20%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%A3%D0%9A%D0%98/81%20%D0%AF%D0%97%D0%AB%D0%9A%D0%9E%D0%97%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%95/81.2%20%D0%A3%D0%9A%D0%A0/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%81%202007.djvu)</del>,
       <del>[коледж НАУ](http://flightcollege.com.ua/library/8%20%D0%A4%D0%98%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%93%D0%98%D0%A7%D0%95%D0%A1%D0%9A%D0%98%D0%95%20%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%A3%D0%9A%D0%98/81%20%D0%AF%D0%97%D0%AB%D0%9A%D0%9E%D0%97%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%95/81.2%20%D0%A3%D0%9A%D0%A0/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%81%202007.doc)</del>,
       <del>[коледж ЧНУ](https://www.college-chnu.cv.ua/images/Books/pravopys.pdf)</del>.

2008. Ющук, проєкт:
       [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%94%D0%BA%D1%82_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%AE%D1%89%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0_(2008)),
       [Культура України](https://elib.nlu.org.ua/view.html?id=8816).

2010. ???.

2012. [УМІФ](https://spelling.ulif.org.ua/),
       [Ізборник](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/pravopys2012.htm) ( [2](http://izbornyk.org.ua/pravopys/pravopys2012.htm)),
       [Ізборник](http://litopys.org.ua/pdf/pravopys2012.pdf) ( [2](http://izbornyk.org.ua/pdf/pravopys2012.pdf)),
       [Україніка](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/ulib/item/ukr0010414).

2015. [Ізборник](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/pravopys2015.htm) ( [2](http://izbornyk.org.ua/pravopys/pravopys2015.htm)),
       [Ізборник](http://litopys.org.ua/pdf/pravopys2015.pdf) ( [2](http://izbornyk.org.ua/pdf/pravopys2015.pdf)),
       [Україніка](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/ulib/item/UKR0009360).

2019. [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81_2019_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83),
       [УМІФ](https://www.ulif.org.ua/system/files/pravopus-new.pdf),
       [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p0moU61Yrg4RskpJYTljxkiAa5vrd0mM/view) (від [ІнМо](http://inmo.org.ua/news/%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81.-%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%96%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%84%D1%96%D1%86%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F.html)).
      Також старіші версії:
      [НАНУ](https://files.nas.gov.ua/PublicMessages/Documents/0/2021/01/210118223223523-1428.pdf),
      [МОН](https://mon.gov.ua/ua/osvita/zagalna-serednya-osvita/navchalni-programi/ukrayinskij-pravopis-2019).

### Інше

Інші колекції:

- Категорії [«Правопис біб»](http://movahistory.org.ua/index.php/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%B1) і [«Правопис»](http://movahistory.org.ua/index.php/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81) на сайті «Хронологія мовних подій в Україні: зовнішня історія української мови» (movahistory).
- [Сайт «Ти - Микола, я - Микола»](https://korchiwjaka.blogspot.com/?view=snapshot) (korchiwjaka).

Огляди:

- Шимлянський, «Найголовніші правила українського правопису (розвідка)», 1927:
   [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx3rm-9lOt18WHRnSUZaNmk0Qms) (від [korchiwjaka](https://korchiwjaka.blogspot.com/2013/02/1921.html)).
- Огієнко, «Нариси з історії української мови: система українського правопису», 1927, Варшава:
   [Культура України](https://elib.nlu.org.ua/object.html?id=9635).
  Передрук, 1990, Вінніпеґ:
   [Diasporiana](https://diasporiana.org.ua/movoznavstvo/3606-ogiyenko-i-narisi-z-istoriyi-ukrayinskoyi-movi-sistema-ukrayinskogo-pravopisu).
- Огієнко, «Історія української літературної мови», 1949, Вінніпег.
  Перевидання/передруки:

  - 2001, Київ:
     [Ізборник](http://litopys.org.ua/ohukr/ohu.htm) ( [2](http://izbornyk.org.ua/ohukr/ohu.htm)).
  - 2-ге вид., випр., 2004, Київ:
     [Україніка](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/ulib/item/UKR0001364),
     [Чтиво](https://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Ohiyenko_Ivan/Istoriya_ukrainskoi_literaturnoi_movy).
- Німчук, «Проблеми українського правопису ⅩⅩ — початку ⅩⅩⅠ ст. ст.», 2002, Київ:
   [Україніка](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/ulib/item/UKR0008884),
   [movahistory](http://movahistory.org.ua/index.php/%D0%9D%D1%96%D0%BC%D1%87%D1%83%D0%BA_%D0%92._%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83_%D0%B2_XX-XXI_%D1%81%D1%82._%D1%81%D1%82.),
   [R2U (без додатків)](https://r2u.org.ua/node/126),
   [vlada.kiev.ua (без додатків)](https://web.archive.org/web/20120605003228/http://www.vlada.kiev.ua/pravopys/1.html) ( [2](https://web.archive.org/web/20100921132422/http://pravopys.vlada.kiev.ua/pravopys/1.html)).
- Німчук, «Історія українського правопису: ⅩⅥ–ⅩⅩ століття», 2004, Київ:
   [movahistory](http://movahistory.org.ua/index.php/%D0%86%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83:_XVI%E2%80%94XX_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D1%82%D1%8F._%D0%A5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%96%D1%8F),
   [Інститут історії України](http://resource.history.org.ua/item/0007903).
- Кацімон, «Загальні уваги до граматик української мови С. Смаль-Стоцького і Ф. Гартнера (1893, 1907, 1914 рр.)», 2013, Київ:
   [Вернадського](http://nbuv.gov.ua/UJRN/Nznuoaf_2013_35_45).
- Схема «Історія українського правопису: хронологія» Павла Литвинчука ([звідси](https://fb.com/groups/375320239720280/posts/1210098496242446); це родовід чинного правопису, тому желехівка, ярижка й т.ін. не додані):

  > [image]
- [Порівняння правописів української мови](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B2_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8) на Вікіпедії.

Фейсбук-спільноти:
[Клясичний український правопис](https://fb.com/groups/pravopys), [Український правопис-2018](https://fb.com/groups/177824792769309),
[Історія українського правопису](https://fb.com/groups/375320239720280).

Answer (score 8):

## Пошук у локалізаціях програмного забезпечення

<sub>Позначення:

 — можна шукати онлайн.</sub>

### Microsoft

[Мовний портал](https://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-us/Search.aspx?sString=&langID=uk-ua) (також можна [стягувати у форматі XML](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/language/terminology)).

### Google Chromium

[Сторінка перекладів на launchpad](https://translations.launchpad.net/chromium-browser/translations/+lang/uk) дозволяє шукати лише в кожній секції окремо, але секцій небагато, найбільші з них:  [chromium-browser](https://translations.launchpad.net/chromium-browser/translations/+pots/chromium-browser/uk/+translate),  [generated-resources](https://translations.launchpad.net/chromium-browser/translations/+pots/generated-resources/uk/+translate).

### KDE

[Сторінка перекладів](https://l10n.kde.org/team-infos.php?teamcode=uk) не дозволяє шукати онлайн, але можна:

- стягувати відразу всі файли локалізації через Subversion, наприклад:

  ```
  svn co svn://anonsvn.kde.org/home/kde/trunk/l10n-kf5/uk/messages
  svn co svn://anonsvn.kde.org/home/kde/trunk/l10n-kf5/uk/docmessages
  ```
- переглядати файли локалізації онлайн, але лише один за одним (що, враховуючи їх кількість, незручно).

### Ubuntu

[Сторінка перекладів на launchpad](https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu) не дозволяє шукати всюди, але дозволяє шукати в кожному пакеті окремо (для зручості можна відсортувати пакети за зменшенням кількості рядків).

### Drupal

[Пошук уже перекладених рядків](https://localize.drupal.org/translate/languages/uk/translate?search=test&status=2&limit=50).

### Translation Project

[Сторінка команди українських перекладачів](http://translationproject.org/team/uk.html) не дозволяє шукати всюди, але дозволяє:

- переглядати локалізації для кожного пакету окремо;
- [стягувати щомісячний tar-архів з локалізаціями всіх пакетів](http://translationproject.org/backups/last/uk.tgz).

### Хотілося б знайти переклади

- Google
- Apple
- Gnome

Comment: @Podarok, і крім того, це перелік інструментів для пошуку перекладів, **що реально використовуються в якомусь ПЗ** — а не просто словників чи сайтів пропозицій.

Answer (score 4):

Перелік ресурсів взято [тут](http://www.mova.info/links.aspx?l1=82).

Вашій увазі пропонуються сайти, безпосередньо пов'язані з різними аспектами функціонування української мови у світах реальному та віртуальному, мовні ресурси від освітянсько-новинних до розважальних.

- [Інтелектуальна кнайпа «Чудова Мова».](http://chumova.com/) Ми створили місце в укрнеті, яке має надавати питво та їжу для розуму, - інтелектуальну кнайпу. Виходячи з назви - "Чудова мова" - зрозуміло, що основна тематика обговорення в кнайпі - це мова. У всіх її найширших проявах, включаючи математику, адже математика - це мова науки. Особлива увага надається зникаючим мовам та мовним технологіям.
- [Хронологія мовних подій в Україні: зовнішня історія української мови.](http://movahistory.org.ua/) Метою сайту є дати користувачеві якомога точнішу й надійнішу інформацію про зовнішню історію української мови. Подано посилання на різнопланові джерела, здебільшого наявні в Інтернеті. Сайт містить також бібліотеку.
- [Повний перелік українських іменників.](http://www.senyk.poltava.ua/projects/cwsearch/cws_search.html) Для створення та розв'язування кросвордів.
- [КіберМова.](http://www.cybermova.com/) Ресурси і програми для письмової та усної української мови
- [ІЗБОРНИК.](http://litopys.org.ua/) Першоджерела та інтерпретації — проект електронної бібліотеки давньої української літератури.
- [БРАМА.](http://www.brama.com/) Одна з найвідоміших інформаційних пошукових систем, що концентрує увагу на розвиток українства у всьому світі. Система об‘єднує широке коло Інтернет-ресурсів. Сайт має розгалужений рубрикатор і систему пошуку.

Comment: Частково повторюєте ті, що були (наприклад, r2u, e2u). Частково посилання не працюють. Але **більшість нові і працюють**, так.
Було б добре, якби Ви змогли це об'єднати і якось з наявною вікі-підповіддю. Щоби був один добре категоризований вікі-список, а не десяток різних.
Можете змінити структуру/форматування моєї вікі-відповіді, якщо вважаєте за доречне. Хоча при дуже сильних змінах я б радше об'єднував в новому місці (ну, типу, поки проект нової структури готується — в окремій відповіді, якщо результат об'єднання всім подобається, стару видалити).

Comment: Ну але це, звісно, Ваше право писати так, як вважаєте за потрібне і там, де вважаєте за потрібне.

Comment: @Sasha, зробив окремою відповіддю, оскільки не було можливості перебрати всі джерела і перевірити на дублікати і тому не хотів засмічувати вашу відповідь. Тому нехай повисить тут, сподіваюсь, що дійдуть руки, щоб все перебрати. І тоді можна буде скомпонувати.

Comment: "Словник.net, який, однак, мусив припинити роботу як тлумачний словник після викупу матеріалів ВТССУМ та юридичного тиску компанією ABBYY (було продано також і те, що фактично скопіювали з 11-томного Словника української мови)" https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%97_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8

Comment: По-доброму, цього допису треба прибрати: богато чого подохло, а значна частина вже є в гинших відповідних роздїлах або можна туда перенести.

Comment: @stegetsj, я теж проти цієї відповіді. І навіть не через те, що більшість посилань перестали бути доступними (частину зниклого все ще можна знайти в архівах), а просто проти некатегоризованих переліків посилань (в ідеалі посилання мають бути не просто категоризовані, а вписані в загальну схему (щоб категорія не повторювалася в різних відповідях)). Але я не наважуюся прибрати, принаймні поки що. Можливо, варто зробити одне з двох: (1) висловити оцінку голосуванням; (2) спробувати викликати автора в чат (чи іншим чином зв'язатися з ним) і порадитися разом.

Comment: [Цю відповідь](/a/9) теж треба буде потім переробити (можливо — остаточно розтягнути в різні інші відповіді, а можливо — є сенс мати якусь overview-відповідь, але в будь-якому разі її треба буде дуже оновити; скоро спробую знайти трішки часу).

Answer (score 4):

(це недописана стаття, яка вимагає переформатування і, можливо, категоризації)

---

## Список джерел, які вважають поважними наші колеги з [Wikipedia](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%97:%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82:%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0)

Словники і довідники, які можна використовувати для перевірки відповідності до сучасної української літературної норми

#### Для перевірки наголосу

- [Складні випадки наголошування слів](http://www.twirpx.com/file/300334/)

#### Для перевірки написання (орфографії)

*

#### Тлумачні словники

- **Сучасний тлумачний словник української мови: 60 000 слів / За заг. ред. д-ра філол. наук, проф. В. В. Дубічинського. — Харків: ВД «ШКОЛА», 2007. — 832 с.** — доволі місткий та зручний тлумачний словник української мови. Як зазначають автори словника, в ньому вводиться сучасна лексика та сленг, серед застарілих слів — слова іх художньої літератури, а також добірка слів з усіх галузей знань. Словник рекомендований Міністерством освіти і науки.
- [ВТССУМ](http://Lingvo.ua)
- [Словник української мови в 11-ти томах. К.: Наукова думка, 1970–1980.](http://sum.in.ua/)

#### Велика чи мала літера

- **В. В. Жайворонок. Велика чи мала літера? Словник-довідник. — К.: Наук. думка, 2004.** — словник рекомендований до друку вченою радою Інституту мовознавства ім. О. О. Потебні НАН України, автор — відомий авторитетний український мовознавець, доктор філологічних наук, [[Жайворонок Віталій Вікторович]]. Входить до серії „Наукове видання «Словники України»“. Окрім того, зручний тим, що [доступний онлайн](http://velyka-chy-mala-litera.wikidot.com/)

#### Довідники з культури мови

- [Словник-довідник з культури української мови](http://ukrknyga.at.ua/load/slovnik_dovidnik_z_kulturi_ukrajinskoji_movi/4-1-0-265)
- [Словник-довідник з українського літературного слововживання](http://www.twirpx.com/file/103521/)

#### Перекладні

Російсько-українські

- [Російсько-українські словники](http://r2u.org.ua/)
- [Російсько-український словник сталих виразів](http://stalivyrazy.org.ua/)
- [Російсько-український словник фізичних термінів](http://ukrknyga.at.ua/load/rosijsko_ukrajinskij_slovnik_fizichnikh_terminiv_za_red_o_b_liskovicha/38-1-0-361)
- [Російсько-український словник. Термінологічна лексика](http://freelib.in.ua/load/92-1-0-1776)
- Російсько-український словник складної лексики С. Караванського

#### Підручники і посібники з пунктуації

*

#### Топоніміка

- [Топонімічний словник України](http://www.toponymic-dictionary.in.ua/)

## Фразеологія

- [Словник фразеологічних синонімів](http://www.rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=index&d=24)
- [Словник фразеологічних антонімів](http://sovremennik.ws/2008/07/03/slovnik_frazeologchnikh_antonmv_ukransko_movi.html)

#### Галузеві словники

- [Фінансовий словник](http://www.twirpx.com/file/459498/)
- [Словник соціологічних і політологічних термінів](http://ukrknyga.at.ua/load/slovnik_sociologichnikh_i_politologichnikh_terminiv_za_red_v_astakhovoji_v_danilenka_a_panova/2-1-0-430)

---

## Список словників, які поважають наші колеги з [Wiktionary](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA:%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2)

Comment: Взагалі, на мою думку, все це варто було б об'єднати у одні відповідь (ну, окрім дуже специфічних речей). Я не кажу, що мій формат списку ідеальний — його можна змінювати, але треба якось пооб'єднувати все. Sashaeve [обіцяв](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/8#comment291_100) почистити свою відповідь від непрацюючих посилань і об'єднати з моєю в одну — але досі він так і висить окремим.

Comment: @Sasha, так, я читав. Можливо, усі джерела можна об'єднати у спільний список, а факт визнання Вікіпедією чи Вікісловником вказувати іконкою, як ви зробили в іншому місці. Плюс, можливо, варто переосмислити категорії відповідно до наших уподобань.

Comment: @Sasha, у колег на Chinese.SE [категорії зроблені](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-mandarin-chinese) у вигляді окремих відповідей (+ посилання на відповіді у тілі запитання)

Comment: так, але в них **категорії** у вигляді окремих відповідей, а не просто N незалежних списків від різних людей. Тобто фактично все одно доведеться змерджити, щоби класифікувати — навіть най ці категорії будуть в окремих відповідях. (Крім того, якщо чесно, я не впевнений, що мені подобається відповідь=категорія, але то вже вторинне питання, спочатку вони мають бути хоч якось розсортовані, а не в кожного свій список.)

Comment: @Sasha, не сперечаюся, що краще робити саме так, як ви кажете. Але, якщо згадати, що ми будуємо Q&A ресурс, то нормою можна вважати також і ситуацію, коли Q має кілька A, які *дещо* перетинаються. Тому я не знаю, як правильно, але просто додав матеріалу для опрацювання.

Comment: Я вважаю, що перелік ресурсів — не Q&A. Це просто інструмент для нашої зручності. Буде безлад — стане незручний. (Я не кажу, що Ви неправильно зробили, що додали — Ви добре зробити, що додали; але потім треба буде все відсортувати (якось; зовсім необов'язково так як в мене, може, в мене поганий спосіб категоризації, я не знаю, мені зі сторони не видно).)

Answer (score 3):

## Ресурси для вивчення українскої

- [Ukrainian Lessons Podcast](http://ukrainianlessons.com/) - безкоштовна серія подкастів розмовною українською для новачків. Оновлюється щотижня.
- [Підбірка](//redd.it/r2oa4y) учбових матеріялів від r/WantDebianThanks.

---

## Ukrainian language learning resources

- [Ukrainian Lessons Podcast](http://ukrainianlessons.com/) - is a free series of podcasts in conversational Ukrainian for beginners. Updated weekly.
- [A collection](//redd.it/r2oa4y) of study from r/WantDebianThanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Загальний здоровий глузд

- [Illustrated book of bad arguments](https://bookofbadarguments.com/) - на жаль, перекладу на українську ще немає. Ця книга показує, як саме люди схильні помилятися у своїй арґументації

---

## Common sense

- [Illustrated book of bad arguments](https://bookofbadarguments.com/) - Unfortunately it hasn't been translated to Ukrainian yet. This book shows how people tend to fail in their argumentation

Comment: варто уточнити, чому ви вважаєте, що підручники з common sense мають відношення до вивчення/дослідження української мови. Наприклад, підручник з аристотелевої логіки або logical fallacies сюди варто додавати?

Comment: @bytebuster так, перепрошую, то в мене трохи "бомбануло" :) спробую виправитися і додати дійсно корисних джерел

Answer (score 1):

## Корпуси

1. [Корпус української мови ЛКЛ ІФ КНУ](http://mova.info/corpus.aspx),
2. [Генеральний регіонально анотований корпус (ГРАК) української мови](//parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/),
3. [Український корпус з лейпцизької колекції](//corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014),
4. [InterCorp v10 Ukrainian на kontext.korpus.cz](//kontext.korpus.cz/first_form?corpname=intercorp_v10_uk),
5. [Пошук в Google-книгах](//books.google.com.ua/) ([лише українською](//google.com.ua/webhp?tbm=bks&lr=lang_uk)),
6. [Паралельний польсько-український](http://www.domeczek.pl/%7Epolukr/),
7. [Паралельний російсько-український на сайті НКРЯ](http://www.ruscorpora.ru/search-para-uk.html),
8. [Браунський корпус української мови](//github.com/brown-uk/corpus), без користувацького інтерфейсу, тобто для машинної обробки, хоча можна [шукати через GitHub](//github.com/brown-uk/corpus/search?q=%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82); також є [NER-анотація](//github.com/lang-uk/ner-uk),
9. [«Український національний лінгвістичний корпус» УМІФ](http://unlc.icybcluster.org.ua/virt_unlc/), нема публічного доступу, лише для Windows.

---

## Corporas

1. [Ukrainian language corpus of LCL of IP of KNU](http://mova.info/corpus.aspx),
2. [General Regionally Annotated Corpus (GRAC) of Ukrainian](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/),
3. [Ukrainian corpus in Leipzig Collection](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014),
4. [InterCorp v10 Ukrainian at kontext.korpus.cz](//kontext.korpus.cz/first_form?corpname=intercorp_v10_uk),
5. [Search in Google Books](http://books.google.com.ua/) ([in Ukrainian only](//www.google.com.ua/webhp?tbm=bks&lr=lang_uk)),
6. [Polish-Ukrainian parallel](http://www.domeczek.pl/%7Epolukr/),
7. [Russian-Ukrainian parallel on the Russian National Corpus site](http://www.ruscorpora.ru/search-para-uk.html),
8. [Brown Ukrainian language corpus](//github.com/brown-uk/corpus), no user-interface, i. e. for machine processing, but can be [searched using GitHub](//github.com/brown-uk/corpus/search?q=%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82); there is [NER-annotation](//github.com/lang-uk/ner-uk),
9. [“Ukrainian national linguistic corpus” of ULIF](http://unlc.icybcluster.org.ua/virt_unlc/), no public access, for Windows only.

Answer (score 1):

## Словники

1. Словник української мови в 11 книгах (СУМ-11: [inmo.org.ua](http://www.inmo.org.ua/sum.html), [sum.in.ua](http://sum.in.ua/), [ukrlit.org](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/slovnyk_ukrainskoi_movy_v_11_tomakh), [slovnyk.ua](https://www.slovnyk.ua/).
2. Словник української мови в 20 книгах (СУМ-20). Від [УЛІФ](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/).
3. Український мовно-інформаційний фонд (УМІФ) надає [словника](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/).
4. [r2u](https://r2u.org.ua/) має такі словники чи збірки: Російсько-український академічний словник (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов), Російсько-український словник (О. Ізюмов), Російсько-український фразеологічний словник (В. Підмогильний, Є. Плужник), Російсько-український словник технічної термінології (І. Шелудько, Т. Садовський), Російсько-український словник ділової мови (М. Дорошенко, М. Станиславський, В. Страшкевич), Російсько-український словник сталих виразів (І. О. Вирган, М. М. Пилинська), Словарь росийсько-український (М.Уманець, А.Спілка.), Російсько-український народний (сучасний) словник, Російсько-український словник військової термінології (С. та О. Якубські), Словник українських наукових і народних назв судинних рослин (Ю. Кобів), Практичний російсько-український словник приказок (Г. Млодзинський, М. Йогансена), Російсько-український словник з інженерних технологій (М. Ганіткевич, Б. Кінаш.), Російсько-український словник складної лексики (С. Караванський), Правописний словник (Г. Голоскевич), Словарь української мови (Б.Грінченко), Словник української мови (Б.Грінченко, за ред. С. Єфремова, А. Ніковського), Словник українсько-російський (А. Ніковський), Тлумачно-стилістичний народний словник, Словник української мови (Д.І.Яворницький), Український стилістичний словник (Огієнко І.), Українська лексикографія XIII—XX ст.djvu (6,7Мб), Список слів з літерою «Ґ» у академічному словнику, Список слів з позначкою «руссизм», Список слів з позначкою «полонизм», Пошук за іншими термінами та скороченнями, Частотний показник українських слів академічного словника (архів 1МБ),
5. [e2u](https://e2u.org.ua/) має такі словники чи збірки: Загальний народний англійсько-український словник, Великий англо-український словник (Є.І. Гороть, Л.М. Коцюк, Л.К. Малімон, А.Б. Павлюк.), Новий українсько-англійський словник (Є.І. Гороть, С.В. Гончарук, Л.К. Малімон, О.О. Рогач.), Фразлекс (англо-український фразеологічний словник) (Василь Старко), Довідник англійських, німецьких та українських ідіом і виразів (Шерік А.Д., Савічук В.Я., Старко В.Ф.), Англійсько-український словник сучасних термінів з ІТ (linux.org.ua), Англійсько-український словник з математики та інформатики (Є. Мейнарович, М. Кратко), Англійсько-українсько-англійський словник наукової мови (фізика та споріднені науки). Частина І англійсько-українська (О. Кочерга, Є. Мейнарович), Англійсько-українсько-англійський словник наукової мови (фізика та споріднені науки). Частина ІІ українсько-англійська (О. Кочерга, Є. Мейнарович), Англійсько-французько-німецько-український словник термінології Європейського Союзу (“Лабораторія наукового перекладу”), Українсько-англійський словник (К.Андрусишин, Я.Крет), Українсько-англійський словник ділової людини (Є. І. Гороть, О. В. Василенко, Н. В. Єфремова [та ін.]), Українсько-англійський словник з прав людини (Лесь Герасимчук), Англо-український тлумачний словник економічної лексики (А. Шимків), Англійсько-український словник-довідник інженерії довкілля (Тимотей Балабан), Глосарій термінів з хімії (Й.Опейда, О.Швайка), Українсько-англійський словник з радіоелектроніки (Богдан Рицар, Леонід Сніцарук, Роман Мисак), Українсько-англійський словник лінгвістичної термінології (Л.В. Коломієць, O.Л. Паламарчук, Г.П. Стрельчук, М.В. Шевченко).
6. [Словопедія](http://slovopedia.org.ua/) має такі словники чи збірки: Великий тлумачний словник (ВТС) сучасної української мови, УСЕ (Універсальний словник-енциклопедія), Орфографічний словник української мови, Фразеологічний словник української мови, Українсько-російський словник, Словник синонімів Полюги, Словник іншомовних слів Мельничука, Словник англіцизмів, Eкономічна енциклопедія, Неправильно — правильно. Волощак, Уроки державної мови (з газети «Хрещатик»), Літературне слововживання, «Як ми говоримо» Антоненка-Давидовича, Український правопис, Економічний словник, Словник мови Стуса, Крилаті вислови, Словник іншомовник слів, Стилістичні терміни, Словник іншомовних соціокультурних термінів, Енциклопедія політичної думки, Словник синонімів Караванського, СЦОТ (Словник церковно-обрядової термінології), Архітектура і монументальне мистецтво, Словник-антисуржик, Словник термінів, уживаних у чинному Законодавстві України, Словник бюджетної термінології, Термінологічний словник з економіки праці, Глосарій термінів Фондового ринку, Моделювання економіки, Власні імена людей, Словар українського сленгу, Музичні терміни, Тлумачний словник з інформатики та інформаційних систем для економістів (Л. С. Козловська, Н. М. Поліщук), Термінологічно-правописний порадник для богословів та редакторів богословських текстів (Інститут богословської термінології та перекладів), Управління якістю (Вакуленко А.В.), Гірничий енциклопедичний словник, 100 видатних iмен України, Словник церковно-обрядової термінології, Словник із соціальної роботи, Словник лемківскої говірки, Словник галицьких говірок, Лексикон львівський, Короткий словник вільномулярських назв, термінів і знаків, Укр. літ. мова на Буковині, Філософський енциклопедичний словник.
7. [Грінченко](http://hrinchenko.com/) ([від УМІФ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/grinch)).
8. [ABBYY Lingvo](https://www.lingvolive.com/en-us).
9. [linguisto](http://linguisto.eu/) (англійсько-, німецько-, французько-українські й частотний).

### Неавторитетні

1. [вікісловник](http://uk.wiktionary.org/).
2. [WorldwideDictionary](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/).
3. [slovnyk.ua](http://slovnyk.ua/).
4. [yenotes](http://yenotes.com).
5. [goroh.pp.ua](https://goroh.pp.ua/).
6. [slovnychok.com.ua](http://slovnychok.com.ua/).
7. [rozum](http://www.rozum.org.ua).
8. [dictionaries24](https://www.dictionaries24.com/uk/).
9. [ABCThesaurus](http://ukrainian.abcthesaurus.com/).
10. [синоніми.укр](https://xn--h1aaldafs6o.xn--j1amh/).
11. [Словник скорочень української мови](http://ukrskor.info/).
12. [Російсько-український словник сталих виразів](http://stalivyrazy.org.ua/). Виргана та Пилинської, призначений для літературних перекладачів, налічує понад 6000 фразеологічних одиниць та сталих виразів.

---

## Dictionaries

1. SUM-11: [inmo.org.ua](http://www.inmo.org.ua/sum.html), [sum.in.ua](http://sum.in.ua/), [ukrlit.org](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/slovnyk_ukrainskoi_movy_v_11_tomakh), [slovnyk.ua](https://www.slovnyk.ua/).
2. SUM-22 on [ULIF](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/).
3. [ULIF](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/).
4. [r2u](https://r2u.org.ua/).
5. [e2u](https://e2u.org.ua/).
6. [slovopedia](http://slovopedia.org.ua/).
7. [Hrinchenko](http://hrinchenko.com/) ([from ULIF](http://services.ulif.org.ua/grinch)).
8. [ABBYY Lingvo](https://www.lingvolive.com/en-us).
9. [linguisto](http://linguisto.eu/) (English-, German-, French-Ukrainian and frequency).

### Non-authoritative:

1. [wiktionary](http://uk.wiktionary.org/).
2. [WorldwideDictionary](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/).
3. [slovnyk.ua](http://slovnyk.ua/).
4. [yenotes](http://yenotes.com).
5. [goroh.pp.ua](https://goroh.pp.ua/).
6. [slovnychok.com.ua](http://slovnychok.com.ua/).
7. [rozum](http://www.rozum.org.ua).
8. [dictionaries24](https://www.dictionaries24.com/uk/).
9. [ABCThesaurus](http://ukrainian.abcthesaurus.com/).
10. [синоніми.укр](https://xn--h1aaldafs6o.xn--j1amh/).
11. [Dictionarie of abbrs](http://ukrskor.info/)
12. [Russian-Ukrainian phrase dictionary](http://stalivyrazy.org.ua/).