# What our Custom Off-Topic Close Reasons should be?

Tags: discussion, scope

#### Background

All sites on the SE network have the following [fixed close reasons](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions):

- Duplicate
- Off-topic because…

  - This question does not appear to be about Ukrainian language, within the scope defined in the [help center](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help).
  - This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network…
  - ***{Here we have three vacant slots}***
  - Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)
- Unclear What You're Asking
- Too Broad
- Primarily Opinion-Based

At the moment, we do not yet have sufficient number of closed questions to collect a reasonably solid statistics, but we need a placeholder for suggested Close Reasons.
[Link](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/admin/flags/close-as-off-topic), visible to moderators and high-reputation users.

#### What should we do

I'm planning this question to stay long-running (several months perhaps).

Please make each suggestion in a **separate answer**.

Please provide with solid research on closed questions explaining why the suggested reason worth adding, and why/how does it differ from the fixed ones and other suggested ones.

Do not add the Close Reasons "for future use" as they are hard to manage.

Answer (score 3):

> Questions that **do not demonstrate an attempt to self-answer** are off-topic. You can improve it by adding what you have done so far, even if it is incomplete.

Тут основна ідея — спонукати авторів запитань робити **власну спробу відповісти** на запитання,
яка, у свою чергу, є не волюнтаризмом з нашого боку, а бажанням точно знати **контекст**.
Контекст же потрібен для того, щоб мати змогу надавати відповідь саме на проблему, яку порушує автор, **і не відгадувати**, який із багатьох можливих контекстів автора цікавить.

Іншими словами, запитання з чітко визначеним контекстом, але без спроби самостійно відповісти — дозволені.

Можливо, варто буде прямо в тексті Off-topic Reason надати посилання на Meta-допис про [словники](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8/) і [етимологічні словники](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/207/).

Comment: Власне, мені особисто така ідея подобається. Але я не впевнений, що воно не буде йти врозріз із [традиціями Stack Exchange](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/308306).

Answer (score 2):

> Questions **seeking phrases or words in English** are off-topic, but you may be able to ask them on English Language Learners Stack Exchange or English Language & Usage Stack Exchange.

This is the only custom off-topic reason on Russian SE, and we had at least [two](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/1065/69) questions that [asked](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/114/69) for the same.

Another question was not about English phrases, but how words of ukrainian origin should be properly spelled in English (about [Kyiv/Kiev](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/286/69)).

Comment: Yes, this is the first one that comes to my mind. We should probably work out some nice formulation so that the "Kiev" question were covered as well.

Comment: I think we can add here "seeking phrases, words **their spelling, or other rules** in English..." Though it's hard to tell if such requests will be regular in the future.

Answer (score 1):

> Questions **asking for translation to Ukrainian** are off-topic. Stack Exchange is not a translation service, so straight-up translation questions like *"What is the Ukrainian word for ___?"* or *"Translate this text for me…"* are discouraged. However, you can ask for *finer* questions that arose *while you've been translating* a text.

Relevant explanation:

- https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22648/

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to [a similar suggestion](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/178/) by @Artemix

> Questions **seeking for translation from Ukrainian to foreign languages** are off-topic. You may try posting them on relevant language sites instead.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to [a similar suggestion](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/196/):

> Questions **asking for translation to Ukrainian** are off-topic unless they contain: (1) the context in which the foreign word is supposed to be used; (2) a free-word explanation of a foreign word or phrase; (3) demonstrate own attempt to answer, and (4) indicate why your own variants do not meet your needs. Stack Exchange is not a translation service, so straight-up translation questions like *"What is the Ukrainian word for ___?"* or *"Translate this text for me…"* are discouraged.

Answer (score -1):

- > Questions related to translation of a foreign-language word that don't clearly clarify the meaning of that foreign-language word are off-topic because out site is devoted to the Ukrainian language (including word-choice problems), but not to other languages (interpreting words of other languages is out of the scope of Ukrainian Language Stack Exchange).  For more information, see […](should write a meta-post).

  The same, but slightly shorter:

  - > Questions related to interpreting words of other languages are off-topic because out site is devoted to the Ukrainian language, but not to other languages (if you're going to ask about a translation of a foreign-language word — as bare minimum you should explain how *you* understand that word, with usage examples).  For more information, see […](should write a meta-post).
- > Questions related to related to translation of a foreign-language word that don't clearly state the context are off-topic, because the problem of finding absolute cross-language equivalents is most often unsolvable.  For more information, see […](should write a meta-post).

Comment: (1) Please make each suggestion in a separate answer. Although all three variants address the same problem, the community should vote out two of the three. (2) A Meta-post should contain one or more answers containing its **argument**. The Custom Close Reason should be merely an essence of the Meta-post and its answers, which don't exist yet. This destroys the whole purpose of referencing a non-existing Meta post. (3) All in all, let's remove this Custom Close Reason candidate and write a good one (or three) based on the results of the suggested Meta post.