# Етимолоґічний словник української мови онлайн?

Tags: discussion, resources

Чому я хочу, щоби він був? Бо для наших людей поки що "етимолоґія" - це щось далеке, вони сміються з назв сіл типу "нижня сироватка", "горішні плавні", це вирішується доступними онлайн-джерелами, де нормальна людина зможе ввести умовне коріння "сир", і дізнатися, що це ПІЄ коріння "текти", а не ходити на російську вікіпедію чи фасмера.

Єдине, що я знаходжу у мережі, це:

https://toloka.to/t32794 або http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm

Це файл .djvu, 6 окремих файлів, якщо точніше.

До того ж, 6 файлів з семи!

Чи є кращі посилання/джерела/ініціативи, що вже створюють онлайн-джерело такого штибу?

P.S. Наскільки складно побудувати сайт з найпростішим функціоналом для етимолоґічного словника? Наприклад, абетковий вказівник + пошук по окремих словах? І скільки це теоретично коштуватиме/чи готовий тут хтось створити такий функціонал?

P.S.S. Чи треба буде купувати/просити в когось права на публікацію цієї інформації? Що там зі словниками?

Comment: Цей же словник [за прямим посиланням](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm), без торентів.

Comment: Я вважаю, що цей допис (у частині [tag:resource-request]) варто перенести на Main.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66126/discussion-between-p-vovk-and-follower).

Answer (score 4):

Вже існує наразї мережевий словник словопоходжень на [Горосі](//goroh.pp.ua/), котрий включає 26 тис. стате́й.

Comment: так, бачив, чекаю, коли вони доповнять конкретно це все.

Answer (score 3):

Здається, [звершилося](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/2780).

Хіба що в них онлайн-версії нема.

Точніше, здається, навіть є, але вона не розміщена ніким на загальнодоступному хостингу.

Comment: Не помітив, що [Follower вже сказав про це](//ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/207#comment758_207). Перепрошую. Але хай відповідь, мабуть, лишається, вона помітніша (і, здається, це саме відповідь — бо їхній продукт, здається, таки здатен бути розміщеним online, просто його не ніхто не розмістив, а чомусь самі автори чомусь не поспішають).