# Українські лінгвістичні корпуси у вільному доступі (або онлайн)

Tags: discussion, resources, корпус

Пропоную складати перелік українських лінгвістичних корпусів у вільному доступі, або що дозволяють пошук онлайн.

Зацікавлених у інших мовних ресурсах прошу до:

- [Деякі корисні онлайн-джерела / Some useful online-sources](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8)

Comment: А в чому мета створювати окреме запитання? Можна просто додати +1 відповідь до «Деяких корисних джерел». Чи  не так?

Comment: @bytebuster, тільки краще не «+1» відповідь, а все ж організувати хаос, що там, на жаль, зараз. Через те, мабуть, gavenkoa і не помітив, що обидва наведені ресурси там вже є.

Comment: Я бачив що там є. Корпуси - це **найважливіший лінгвістичний ресурс**, тому окрема тема.  Також зверніть увагу на назву тієї теми. У випадку англійської я корстуюсь деякими офлайн корпусами.

Comment: «Найважливіший лінгвістичний ресурс» — згоден. Але все ж дублювати, по-моєму, не варто (принаймні дублювати так, що переліки відрізняються — там є якийсь корпус, якого немає тут, а тут є якийсь, якого немає там). Власне, початковою метою створення тієї відповіді було скласти **мінімальний** набір ресурсів, про який має знати **кожен** (звісно, там були правопис, корпуси і СУМ-11) — але потім я про це **забув** і став розширювати — а потім приєдналися інші і, замість розширювати, почали створювати окремі відповіді. Але все ж, по-моєму, якщо буде дві теми — то це мінус популярності для обох.

Comment: Тож, по-моєму, буде значно краще, якщо Ви свіжим оком порадите як в тій темі лад навести, щоби було читабельніше для тих, хто туди заходить. (P.S.: А що не так із назвою?)

Answer (score 1):

- http://www.ruscorpora.ru/search-para-uk.html **Національний корпус російської мови**. Паралельні російсько-українські тексти. Тільки онлайн. Пошук по ключовим словам, граматичним функціям, тезаурусу і іншими додатковими ознаками.
- http://www.mova.info/corpus.aspx **Корпус української мови проекту mova.info**. Пошук за лексемою, без змін, за частиною мови.