# Онлайн-тести на знання українскої мови?

Tags: support, resources

Хочу потестувати своє знання мови. Чи є в мережі гідні тести для тренувань?
Бажано шоб з помилкою показувало також відповідне правило граматиці. Ну це я забагато хочу, я знаю :)
[Оце питання](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%8F%D0%BA%D1%96-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD-%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0-some-useful-online-sources) дивився, але там з тестів тільки ReadMe, тести на читання.

Comment: Контекст: автор запитує про ресурси, для яких нема навіть категорії у Meta post за посиланням. І цікавиться, що у такому випадку робити.

Comment: На платформі [It's quiz](http://www.itsquiz.com) є один тест, але зовсім ніякий. Тільки числівники.

Answer (score 3):

#### Набори тестів

- [Webpen](https://webpen.com.ua/index.html) — спочатку дається теорія, а далі вправи. Перевірка правопису.
- Сайт «Мова — ДНК нації»: усілякі [вправи](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/exercises) й [диктанти](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/duktantu)
- ЗНО з української мови й літератури (та інших предметів):

  - [на сайті Освіта.UA](https://zno.osvita.ua/ukrainian/)
  - [на сайті Test ZNO](http://testzno.com.ua/?Itemid=2)
- [Тести з української мови для 5–11 класів школи від Вінницького міського центру дистанційної освіти](https://distance.edu.vn.ua/ukr_m_test/)

#### Коротенькі тести

- [Онлайн-тест словникового запасу української мови](https://www.arealme.com/ukrainian-vocabulary-size-test/uk/) на сайті arealme.com
- BBC News Україна:

  - [Як добре ви знаєте українську мову? Тест](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/news-47291127)
  - [Як добре ви знаєте українську-2. Тест](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/news-54876962)

Answer (score 0):

Спробуйте перевершити мій індивідуальний рекорд

https://www.arealme.com/ukrainian-vocabulary-size-test/uk/

[image]