# Посилання не підтримуються в коментарях

Tags: support

Посилання означені через Markdown не підтрімуються в коментарях. [Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) взагалі підтрімується в коментарях на http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com? 
Приклад дивиться в моєму коменті [тут](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187/%D0%9E%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8).

Comment: У вашому коментарі треба вказати http:// перед адресою посилання.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Markdown підтримується, але дуже обмежено. 
Дивіться у кінці документа за вашим посиланням: [Comment formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting):

> Comments support only bold, italic, code and links; in addition, a few shorthand links are available.

Тобто підтримується напівжирний, курсив, "код" та посилання, а також короткі посилання як `[edit]`, тощо.

У вашому коментарі треба вказати `http://` перед адресою посилання.

Comment: Добре. Ніколи не задумувався про то шо протокол це обов'язково. Здавалося, шо і так працювало :)

Comment: @Suncatcher, так, протокол — це обов'язково. Формально кажучи, `example.com/sample` — це теж коректна веб-адреса, але **інша** за `http://example.com/sample` (бо `example.com/sample` є **відносною** веб-адресою і на сторінці `http://foo.com/path/file` воно інтерпретуватиметься веб-оглядачем як `http://foo.com/path/example.com/sample`, розумієте?). Але протокол можна опускати, почитаючи веб-адресу з `//`, наприклад, `//example.com/sample` (це означає «використовувати поточний протокол»).